# Angular 2 OverlayView does not set position of infoWindow

Tags: typescript, angular

First of all I have an interface InfoWindow which contains 2 methods the open is for the markers, but I have create a custom marker with an overlayView.

```
export interface InfoWindow {
  constructor(opts?: InfoWindowOptions): void;
  open(map?: GoogleMap, anchor?: MVCObject): void;
  openTest(map?: GoogleMap, anchor?: MVCObject): void;
}
```

google-map-info-window.ts:

```
  open(): Promise<void> { return this._infoWindowManager.open(this); }
  openTest(): Promise<void> { return this._infoWindowManager.openTest(this); }

  /**
   * Holds the marker that is the host of the info window (if available)
   */
  hostMarker: SebmGoogleMapMarker;

  hostOverlayView: SebmGoogleMapOverlayView;
```

Than I have an addEventListener:

```
private _addEventListeners() {
console.log('event listener added');
this._overlayViewManager.createEventObservable('click', this).subscribe(() => {
console.log('click');
  if (this._infoWindow != null) {
      this._infoWindow.openTest();
  }
  this.markerClick.next(null);
});
```

}

Where it is executing the `openTest` method which looks like this:

```
openTest(infoWindow: SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow): Promise<void> {
console.log('openTest');

return this._infoWindows.get(infoWindow).then((w) => {
  if (infoWindow.hostOverlayView != null) {
    return this._overlayViewManager.getNativeoverlayView(infoWindow.hostOverlayView).then((overlayView) => {
      return this._mapsWrapper.getMap().then((map) => w.open(map, overlayView));
   });
  }
   return this._mapsWrapper.getMap().then((map) => w.open(map));
 });
}
```

Above when I set w.openTest(map, overlayView) & w.open(map) it throws me this error: `EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: w.openTest is not a function`

Than the following method:

```
 getNativeoverlayView(overlayView: SebmGoogleMapOverlayView): Promise<OverlayView> {
  console.log('returned');
  return this._overlayViews.get(overlayView);
}
```

And the `infowindow` is not opening when the "marker" is clicked, I did the exact same as the marker only than for my custom overlay view. Or is it not possible to create a `hostOverlayView` of type `SebmGoogleMapOverlayView`

It is showing but it is not setting its position..

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add a function in google-map-types.ts which returns the LatLng => `this.overlayView.getPosition = function() {
      var position = self.latlng
      return position;
    }`